# ¿Cómo obtener la ruta absouta de archivos dentro de subcarpetas con CMD y Batch?

Tags: cmd, batch

Tengo un directorio lleno de carpetas, dentro de esas carpetas hay varios archivos .txt. Algo así.

```
+Carpeta1
|---Archivo1.txt
|---Archivo2.txt
|---Archivo3.txt
+Carpeta2
|---Archivo1.txt
|---Archivo2.txt
|---Archivo3.txt
+Carpeta3
|---Archivo1.txt
|---Archivo2.txt
|---Archivo3.txt
```

Lo que quiero es obtener la ruta absoluta de esos archivos .txt para pasarselos como argumento a un programa usando un batch. Algo así.

```
programa.exe "C:/Carpeta1/Archivo1.txt"
```

Por ahora he llegado a esto:

```
@echo off


::Guarda el nombre de la carpeta en la variable "dirname"
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir  /a:d /b') do (Echo Procesando carpeta: "%%D" & set dirname=%%~nD)  & call :procesaCarpeta
goto :eof


:procesaCarpeta    
::Nos metemos dentro de la carpeta
cd   %dirname%


::Guarda el nombre de los archivos .txt en la variable "fname"
for %%i in (*.txt) do (Echo Procesando el archivo: "%%i" & set fname=%%~ni) & call :procesaArchivos
goto :eof   



:procesaArchivos    
::Pasar la ruta del archivo al programa
programa.exe "%cd%\%fname%.txt"



::Salir del directorio
cd ..


goto :eof
goto :eof
```

El problema es que no sé dónde/cómo poner el **(cd ..)** para que procese todos los archivos que hay dentro de la carpeta antes de salir del directorio porque ahora mismo solo lo hace con un archivo y sale de la carpeta. O tal vez se pueda plantear todo de otra forma. La verdad es que soy bastante malo con esto del CMD. ¿Un poco de ayuda? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que me estaba complicando la vida mas de lo necesario :-)
He encontrado una solución super simple a este problema. Lo dejo por aquí a por si a alguien mas le puede ser útil.

```
@echo off

For /R "%cd%" %%G IN (*.txt) do (set fname=%%G)  & call :procesa
pause
goto :eof


:procesa
programa.exe "%fname%"
goto :eof
```

Eso es todo lo que hacia falta, lo he sacado de esta página por si a alguien le interesa.
https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html